# constructor called when instatiating a nullable value type

Tags: c#, nullable

```
using System;
public class C {
    public void Main() {
        
        int j1=5;
        int? j=7;
    }
}
```

Here is the IL code for initializing `j1` and `j`

```
 IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
    IL_0002: stloc.0
    IL_0003: ldloca.s 1
    IL_0005: ldc.i4.7
    IL_0006: call instance void valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<int32>::.ctor(!0)
```

From the IL I can see that when I use Int32 no constructor gets called but when I use Nullable a constructor is called in order to put the value inside the variable.
Why is that so? 
I can only imagine it is because the Nullable type must be able to be null but both non-nullable and nullable ints atre structs internally. So why isn't there a constructor in case of Int32?

All of this is taking into account Jon skeet's answer that when a nullable int32 is null, It does not point anywhere but It is null by Itself.
[? (nullable) operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183818/nullable-operator-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Note that the constructor is so short as to be most likely inlined, so performance-wise it shouldn't matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [Reference Source of `struct Nullable<T>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs).

It has this constructor:

```cs
public Nullable(T value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.hasValue = true;
}
```

And the `Value` and `HasValue` properties are getter-only. This means that the constructor must be called to assign a value to a `Nullable<T>`.

There is no such thing like a stand-alone nullable `7` constant. `Nullable<T>` wraps the value assigned to it.

Btw., `null` is assigned by setting the memory position to 0 directly and bypassing the constructor according to [Jb Evain's answer to: How does the assignment of the null literal to a System.Nullable type get handled by .Net (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/711678/880990).

Comment: Thank you, I was just wondering, the Nullable<int32> would you call it a refernce type(struct in this case) ?

Comment: It is a `struct`. So, no, it is a value type, i.e., a variable does contain its content directly and not a reference to an object.

Comment: Okay, soryy if I am asking silly questions. But if regular int is a struct as well then how does it get constructed without a constructor? I really apologize if the question is stupid.

Comment: Primitive types have special support in C#. See: [Why C# implements integer type as a struct and not as a primitive type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40845063/880990).